# How to render the value of v-for based on the condition(v-if) provided in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to implement the condition provided in the code. My last attempt was like in the one in the code.

```
  <ul class = "details" v-for = "(value, propertyName) in items[this.index]" :key = "value.id">
    <li v-if="{{propertyName}} == 'IndustryIdentifiers'">Data not available</li>
    <li v-else>{{value}}</li>
 </ul>
```

How can the following be implemented:
v-if="{{propertyName}} == 'IndustryIdentifiers'"

Comment: Hi, can you create a snippet on jfiddle and post the link here so we can help you ?

Comment: remove the brackets from `propertyName` in your v-if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{{ }}` syntax is used to wrap a JavaScript expression that should be output as text. It isn't necessary to use the braces to access data in other contexts. In the case of a `v-if` the attribute value is already an expression and there's no need to include any special characters to pull in data values.

So it'd be just `v-if="propertyName === 'IndustryIdentifiers'"`:

```html
<ul class="details" v-for="(value, propertyName) in items[this.index]" :key = "value.id">
    <li v-if="propertyName === 'IndustryIdentifiers'">Data not available</li>
    <li v-else>{{ value }}</li>
</ul>
```

Here I'm assuming that `item[this.index]` is an object rather than an array, which is implied by the way you've written your loop.

You could also write it like this:

```html
<ul class="details" v-for="(value, propertyName) in items[this.index]" :key = "value.id">
    <li>{{ propertyName === 'IndustryIdentifiers' ? 'Data not available' : value }}</li>
</ul>
```

You should also be able to remove the `this.` from the `index` unless it's also declared locally.

I also wonder whether you're intentionally creating a separate list for each value, with each list only containing a single item. Difficult to know exactly what you're trying to achieve but I would guess that you want the loop inside the `<ul>` rather than on the `<ul>`. If you only have a single `<li>` (as in my second example) then you could move the `v-for` onto the `<li>`. If you want to stick to having two `<li>` elements with `v-if`/`v-else` then you'll need to wrap them in a `<template>` tag to hold the `v-for`.